# Want to do On-Premises Setup of Kafka cluster(confluent community platform) on Azure

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I want to do On-Premises Setup of Kafka cluster(confluent community platform) on Azure with 3 nodes and load balancer.

I want to use the confluent services like **RestProxy, Schema Registry & Connectors**(s3, elastic search, etc...)

Below reference, I have checked already

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/best-practices-for-running-apache-kafka-on-aws/

https://medium.com/code-tech/kafka-in-aws-with-ssl-offloading-using-load-balancer-c337da1435c3

**what would be the best architectural setup I should follow?**

---

**Approach I took**

I followed the below architecture and did the setup on Azure.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for architecure and deployment recommendations.

Comment: Also, S3 Connect won't work in Azure because S3 doesn't exist there. And "On-Premises" doesn't really mix with Azure, a cloud platform

Comment: @cricket_007, Thanks for your response. I don't think, we can't post any architecturally related recommendation on this portal. Please recommend if you have any good approach but don't vote down. And "On-Premises", I mean to manage the kafka cluster on your own(maybe It's the wrong word in this case).

Comment: @cricket_007, Regarding S3 connect, It works wherever you do the setup of confluent kafka platform. In the S3 connect setup you have to pass your target S3 information(s3 bucket url and key)

Comment: See http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ ... Basically, you should *try* installing it following the resources you've already gathered, then come back with any problems you're running into. IMO, you don't require a load balancer, as it becomes a single point of failure, and you need to ensure it has higher uptime and redundancies than the services behind it (which is not provided by plain install of Confluent Platform)

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for your clarification. I have tried myself and after that I posted. But the question should have all action item I have followed.

Comment: Okay, and what issues are you having? Again, this site isn't really for recommendations on "best architecture". If all you want is Confluent Platform, then I would personally suggest Confluent Cloud. But if you really wanted to install it all yourself, there are Terraform and Ansible modules on Github to deploy in the cloud or anywhere else